# Malformed communication packet mysql just with INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, next.js

I used the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) package to connect mysql and nextjs database

I applied a lot of SELECT codes and it works fine , But when trying to implement
INSERT INTO   Received the following error
**Malformed communication packet.**

Thank you